# To display the content only after clicking publish button in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a course module where once created it displays in the front end. I want to add a publish and unpublish button for that. Where only when publish button is clicked it should show the details in the front end.

So for that i added the column in db.

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean "publish"
  t.boolean "unpublish"
  t.index ["slug"], name: "index_courses_on_slug", unique: true
 end
```

routes:

```
resources :courses do
  collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
  member do
    post :copy
    get :publish
    get :unpublish
  end
end
```

and in course_controller i defined an action

```
def publish
 publish_course = @course.dup
 publish_course.title = "Copied from:#{@course.id} #{@course.title}"
 respond_to do |format|
   if clone_course.save
     format.html { redirect_to publish_course, notice: "Course was successfully published from #{@course.id}: #{@course.title}." }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @publish_course }
   else
     format.html {  redirect_to courses_path, alert: "Please try again. Something went wrong.." }
     format.json { render json: publish_course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end
```

I need to wire it up with the frontend now. How to display this? Can anyone help?

course would be displaced in this upcomingcourse.html.erb

```
<div class="componentheading">
    <h2><%= @location.location_name %></h2> <h3>Upcoming Courses at this location</h3>
</div>
<% @courses.sort { |a,b| (a.try(:start_date) || a.try(:date))  <=> (b.try(:start_date) || b.try(:date)) }.each do |course|%>
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="media">
       <div class="mat_event_image_holder col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 ">
          <div class="mat_event_image_holder_inner">
            <%=image_tag course.image_url, :size => "150x200", :class=> 'uk-overlay-scale'%>
          </div>
       </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

and the controller which renders that is

```
def upcomingcourse
    @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
    @location = Location.friendly.find(params[:location])
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category])
    @courses = @location&.courses || []
    @events = @location&.events || []
    @courses  = @courses + @events
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know why are you cloning the course record just to make it published/unpublished. Below approach is a bit different from yours. Use if you feel it's better.

---

Why do you have two separate columns to store the published/unpublished state? If one of them is `true`, other would (and should) always be `false`. Right?

You can drop one of them, specifically *"unpublish"* and still handle this feature using another one (with a rename). [Change your database schema](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method) to following:

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean "published"
  t.index ["slug"], name: "index_courses_on_slug", unique: true
end
```

Now, add routes and controller actions to update the state of a course:

*config/routes.rb*

```
resources :courses do
  member do
    put :publish
    put :unpublish
  end
end
```

Note, i used `put` instead of `get`, as we are updating the course record here and 'PUT' request is the appropriate request type to do that.

*courses_controller.rb*

```
before_action :fetch_course, only: [:publish, :unpublish]

def publish
  if @course.update(published: true)
    render_success
  else
    render_failure
  end
end

def unpublish
  if @course.update(published: false)
    render_success
  else
    render_failure
  end
end

private

def fetch_course
  @course = Course.find(params.require(:id))
end
```

I believe you already have the logic in view to make requests to these actions on clicking "Publish"/"Unpublish" button.

**Update**

Including the logic to show only published courses to users:

Add a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in `Course` model to fetch courses with `published: true`:

*models/course.rb*

```
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```

*whatever_controller.rb*

```
def upcomingcourse
  @users = User.order('created_at DESC')
  @location = Location.friendly.find(params[:location])
  @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category])

  @courses = @location ? @location.courses.published : []

  # Don't know what are these, but it should work.
  @events = @location&.events || []
  @courses = @courses + @events
end
```

Comment: the course controller is for the admin team , there all the courses should be displayed. But the course which is selected as published only those courses to be displayed in frontend page. I have updated my question it has my view code that is displayed in frontend

Comment: i changed that and when i try to publish a course it tells that it could not find the course id and shows error in this line

Comment: def fetch_course
      @course = Course.find(params.require(:id))
end

Comment: This question is already very broad and this error is not directly related to what your original question was: "Trouble in displaying published only courses to users". This answer hopefully solves that part of your application. For further issues, i would recommend you asking different question. Extending the scope of an existing question is not good practice.

Comment: @Amy, try `def fetch_course
  @course = Course.friendly.find(params.require(:id))
end` or method that you used to find course before method publish. That answer is correct.

Comment: ya the method is correct leo  but when i click on publish button it tells it cannot find the course, it throws the error

Comment: @Amy most probably, something is wrong with the way you send request to publish/unpublish courses. We can't tell what exactly unless we have the view code and server logs for the request.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh in my course.index.view i have added a publish link for the course where it fetches the particular id of the course

Comment: <% @courses.each do |course| %>
        <tr>
         <td><%= course.id %></td>
         <td>
          <%= link_to "Publish", publish_course_path(course), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'You want to publish the course?' } %>
          <%= link_to "UnPublish", unpublsh_course_path(@courses), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'You want to unpublish the course?' } %>
         </td>
        </tr>
       <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jagdeep already suggested: I would change the show part to use a scope on the Course model:

course.rb

```
class Course < App:Model
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

Then update your show method like this:

courses_controller.rb

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @course = Course.published.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

This will give a RecordNotFound error in case the record is not published. I guess this is more Rails'ish, by delegating this logic to the Model, instead of handling it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply